# Double for loop, how to set non-continuous index?

Tags: matlab

If I want to construct a double for loop, but for `index k` I don't want it to be continuous index but like [1,2,4,7]. I tried to do the following, and it did not work.

```
for i=1:100
    for k=1:2:4:7;
        b(i)=i*k;
    end
end
```

Anyone could help me deal with that?

Comment: Quick note: it may be just the simplification of your example but in this specific example the value `b(i)` would be overwritten 3 times and only retain the value calculated with the last value of `k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to construct an array, you don't want to necessarily use the [colon (`:`) operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) unless you want to create a *range* of values (like you do when you want `i` to be all values between 1 and 100), instead you want to use square brackets (`[]`) with comma separators to explicitly create an array of discrete values.

```
k = [1,2,4,7];
```

Now that you do this you can specify your loop like you had it with this small substitution for the values of `k`

```
kvalues = [1,2,4,7];
for i = 1:100
    for k = 1:numel(kvalues)
        b(i) = i * kvalues(k);
    end
end
```

Notice that I have defined `kvalues` *once* outside of the loop so that it is not created every iteration through the outer loop (thanks to [@dfri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090030/double-for-loop-how-to-set-non-continuous-index/36090283?noredirect=1#comment59825153_36090283) for pointing this oversight out)

The way that you have your loop written, you're actually *over-writing* the value of `b(i)` every time through the inner loop. I'm not sure if that's what you intended to do. If it is, then you can reduce your loop to the following:

```
b = k(end) * (1:100);
```

Otherwise, if you meant to have it be `b(i,k) = i * k`, you could rewrite this with `bsxfun`.

```
b = bsxfun(@mtimes, [1,2,4,7], (1:100).');
```

Comment: Note that the `for k = [1,2,4,7]` method will create a new array `[1,2,4,7]` in each iteration over the invariant `i`, yielding quite an unnecessary overhead (much slower than e.g. your latter solutions), possibly worth mentioning in an otherwise nice answer. The `bsxfun` solution is neat, +1.

Comment: @dfri Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated it to initialize once. Thanks!

Comment: Weird: even after your fix (defining `kvalues` prior to loop) it still runs horribly much slower than e.g. `bsxfun` solution (fastest) or my solution below (setting `k` as index of "non-cont" vector rather than the value of it), [e.g. see this gist](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/6936262887f13695cbf1) (note: not caring here about the overwriting `b(i) = ...`, just to compare loop behaviour). I can't explain this though, any ideas?

Comment: Possibly Matlab optimizes the simple `= X:x:Y` syntax in loops (`for invariant = 1:stepSize:last`), whereas assigning values to the invariant from a vector uses some other, non-optimized, method. (I see the same slow behaviour for a simple contiguous-value vector `kvector = 1:4`, so it doesn't seem to depend on the actual values in the vector, but the use for `for invariant = aVector` in the `for` loops).

Comment: @dfri Not surprised at all that `bsxfun` is faster as that is almost always the case. As far as why my update isn't as fast as yours, it's likely because the internals of the inner loop are a little more unknown since I grab kvalues every time and the JIT compilation has a harder time.  Interestingly, if you replace `numIndices` with `numel(nonContIndex)` inside of the loop you'll get the same performance.

Comment: @dfri You would think that if it optimizes `X:x:Y` that it would *definitely* optimize a constant array like `[1,2,4,7]` that can't possibly be changed.

Comment: I agree, that specific example does strike me as strange. Probably a peculiarity of the JIT compiler, as you say; possibly relevant information [in this thread]. Anyway, sorry for going off-topic, but this was more interesting for me than the actual Q&A ;) (this is almost worth asking a question about, but I'll look around first to see if one already exists).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `k=1:2:4:7` will not work as you intend. Usually we make use of the "two colon" syntax to describe a non-default (`1`) step size from the given `start` to `end` values, `k = start:stepSize:end`. Using an additional colon here even yields a Matlab warning (*"third colon probably not intended?"*).

One possible workaround is to let your "non-continuous" indices reside in a vector and extract members of this vector in the inner `for` loop as follows

```
nonContIndex = [1; 2; 4; 7];
numIndices = numel(nonContIndex);
b = zeros(100,numIndices);
for i=1:100
  for k=1:numIndices
    b(i,k)=i*nonContIndex(k);
  end
end
```

As noted by comments and the other answer: if `b` is simply a vector, your original loop will overwrite the `b(i)`:th entry for each run of the inner loop. The above assumes that you in fact want a 2D matrix as a result.